# Getting last day of previous month in HIVE query

Tags: oracle, hive, sysdate

I am new to HIVE and I need to get the last day of previous month from a table in hive.

SQL equivalent ---

```
select last_day(add_months(sysdate,-1)) from dual;
```

I could only get previous day in the internet which is something like

```
select * 
from table1 
where dt >= from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()-1*60*60*24, 'yyyyMMdd');
```

could someone please help me with the query?

Thanks
Rakesh

Comment: Hi, you can check this question. It is almost the same with yours. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548584/find-last-day-of-a-month-in-hive

Comment: Thanks Canburak,, I did something like this -----  date_sub(from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'yyyy-MM-dd'), day(from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'yyyy-MM-dd')))

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
DATE_SUB(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()),DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP())))

Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 1 seconds 850 msec
OK
2016-03-31
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select date_add(current_date,-day(current_date));
```