# hive get each month end date

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want each month last date ,like Jan - 31 , Feb - 28 , so on. 
I tried below with current_date and it works but when I use my date column it returns null:

```
SELECT datediff(CONCAT(y, '-', (m + 1), '-', '01'), CONCAT(y, '-', m, '-', '01')) FROM 
(SELECT
month(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(C_date, 'yyyyMMdd'),'yyyy-MM-dd') ) as m, 
year(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(C_date, 'yyyyMMdd'),'yyyy-MM-dd') ) as y, 
day(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(C_date, 'yyyyMMdd'),'yyyy-MM-dd') )
from table2 ) t
```

returns :

```
_c0
    NULL 

SELECT
month(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(C_date, 'yyyyMMdd'),'yyyy-MM-dd') ) as m, 
year(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(C_date, 'yyyyMMdd'),'yyyy-MM-dd') ) as y, 
day(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(C_date, 'yyyyMMdd'),'yyyy-MM-dd') )
from table2) t
```

returns:

```
m   | y  | _c2|
3   |2017|  21|
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find last day of a month in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548584/find-last-day-of-a-month-in-hive)

Comment: select last_day(current_date) - returns full date 2017-12-31 , i need only 31 so unless i substr i would not get 31

Comment: There is calendar utilities in hive, so try with hive UDF functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `last_day()` and `day()` functions:

```
hive> select day(last_day(current_date)) ;
OK
31
Time taken: 0.079 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Apply `to_date()` to convert your column before applying `last_day()`.