# Hive query to return last date of each month for 3 years

Tags: date, hive, calendar, hiveql

Please provide hive query to return last date of each month in `'yyyy-mm-dd'` format for 3 years.

Comment: You might find this useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548584/find-last-day-of-a-month-in-hive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitute start and end dates in this example with yours. How it works: `space` function generates string of spaces with length = number of days returned by `datediff()` function, split by space creates an array, posexplode explodes an array, returning position of the element in the array, which corresponds to the number of days.  Then date_add('${hivevar:start_date}',s.i) returns dates for each day, `lest_day()` function (exists in Hive since 1.1version) converts each date to the last day (need `distinct` here). Run this example:

```
set hivevar:start_date=2015-07-01;
set hivevar:end_date=current_date;

select distinct last_day(date_add ('${hivevar:start_date}',s.i)) as last_date 
  from ( select posexplode(split(space(datediff(${hivevar:end_date},'${hivevar:start_date}')),' ')) as (i,x)
        ) s
order by last_date
;
```

Output:

```
OK
2015-07-31
2015-08-31
2015-09-30
2015-10-31
2015-11-30
2015-12-31
2016-01-31
2016-02-29
2016-03-31
2016-04-30
2016-05-31
2016-06-30
2016-07-31
2016-08-31
2016-09-30
2016-10-31
2016-11-30
2016-12-31
2017-01-31
2017-02-28
2017-03-31
2017-04-30
2017-05-31
2017-06-30
2017-07-31
2017-08-31
2017-09-30
2017-10-31
2017-11-30
2017-12-31
2018-01-31
2018-02-28
2018-03-31
2018-04-30
2018-05-31
2018-06-30
2018-07-31
Time taken: 71.581 seconds, Fetched: 37 row(s)
```