# Number of Days in a month HIVE

Tags: sql, date, hive, hiveql

Can someone let me know a simple way to get # of days in a month in HIVE SQL based on current_date.
e.g. 2021-02-16 = 28 days,  2021-06-30 = 30 days etc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find last day of a month in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548584/find-last-day-of-a-month-in-hive)

Answer (score 0):

Use

`day(last_day(current_date))`

`last_day(date)` returns last day date, `day(date)` returns day part of the date, int

See manual here: [Language Manual - Date Functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/hive/languagemanual+udf#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions)